# refresh child window from parent window

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript

i have the refresh button in my parent window,

when i click refresh  button ,

i want to refresh my child window ,

> window.location.href='add_billing_order_frm.php?session_re_genrate=new

This snippet redirecting the page instead refresh ,

I thing there is a snippet like

> opener.document.location.reload(true);

but this one for parent window refresh, but i want for child window wiht URL location option

```
function show_billing_order_form(url){
   var childWindow = window.open(url);
}

function refresh_my_child_window(){
   return childWindow.location.reload('add_billing_order_frm.php');
}
```

To open a popup window(child window) , i used this show_billing_order_form call back ,

To refresh the child window , i add one refresh icon in my parent window , To refresh the child window , in that refresh icon onclick i called refresh_my_child_window ,

but function refreshing my child window..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When opening your child window from the parent, remember the return value in a variable somewhere:

```
var childWindow = window.open(/* ... */);
```

...and when you want to refresh the child:

```
childWindow.location.reload();
```

Note that some browsers will prevent access to `childWindow.location.reload` if the parent and child aren't loaded from the [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Here's a quick-and-dirty example ([live copy](https://output.jsbin.com/kojedibuhi/1) — note: the live copy only works in non-edit mode, like the link given, because otherwise JSBin uses `null.jsbin.com` instead of `output.jsbin.com` and so the origin doesn't match):

HTML:

```
<input type='button' id='btnOpen' value='Open Child'>
<input type='button' id='btnClose' value='Close Child'>
<input type='button' id='btnRefresh' value='Refresh Child'>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    var childWindow;

    document.getElementById('btnOpen').onclick = openChildWindow;
    document.getElementById('btnClose').onclick = closeChildWindow;
    document.getElementById('btnRefresh').onclick = refreshChildWindow;

    function openChildWindow() {
        if (childWindow) {
            alert("We already have one open.");
        } else {
            childWindow = window.open(location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/cotokijigu/1");
        }
    }

    function closeChildWindow() {
        if (!childWindow) {
            alert("There is no child window open.");
        }
        else {
            childWindow.close();
            childWindow = undefined;
        }
    }

    function refreshChildWindow() {
        if (!childWindow) {
            alert("There is no child window open.");
        } else {
            childWindow.location.reload();
        }
    }
})();
```

**Caveat**: I would never recommend hooking up event handlers with `onclick` properties as above. Instead, I'd use `addEventListener` (on standards-based browsers) or `attachEvent` (on IE), by using a library or a utility function like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247). Used the properties above to avoid obscuring the main point.

Comment: @PiyushBalapure - It does, it's just that JSBin switched from `http` to `https` and so the example stopped working because the parent was on `https` but the child was opened with `http`. I've updated the live example link.

Answer (score -1):

```
var childWindow = window.open("","name",/* .. */);
childWindow.location.reload();
```