# Launch a new tab and reload original page

Tags: javascript, html

In my LAMP stack application I create invoices in pdf format. The first screen allows selections of purchase items to be included in the invoice. My pdf opens in a new tab using the $_POSTed form data which works fine, but I would also like to simultaneously reload the first page as I also update the status of purchases selected for the pdf invoice and I want the selection screen to reflect this. Any ideas anyone? NB Native Javascript or PHP solutions only please.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059179/refresh-child-window-from-parent-window

Comment: Close, but no cigar - that Q is to do with refreshing a child window from parent. I want to open a child window and refresh the parent at the same time.

Comment: @Peter, reload and check my answer.

Comment: I just had exactly the same problem as you, im building exactly the same thing as you :) it would be interesting to see what you're doing :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
<a onclick="open_in_new_tab_and_reload('./path_to_pdf.pdf')" href="#">PDF</a>

<script>
function open_in_new_tab_and_reload(url)
{
  //Open in new tab
  window.open(url, '_blank');
  //focus to thet window
  window.focus();
  //reload current page
  location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Comment: OK great, reload worked, for my situation I used:  
    `theform.submit();`
    `location.reload();`  
as I needed the form data to be POSTed. Thanks.

Comment: @Lawrence You legend :D iv been scratching my head for quite a while over this problem. Thanks