# How to open a new URL with javascript and without cache?

Tags: javascript

I want to load a "new" url and force a refresh on that.
If I do something like this:

```
window.open(url,"_self");
location.reload(true);
```

Then the the old URL will be reloaded.
If I just use "open" the cache is used.

The URL from server is the same. For example:

```
currentURL = "index.html#/TheOldURL";
window.open("index.html#/TheNewURL","_self");
location.reload(true);
```

The code would do a reload of `index.html#/TheOldURL`.
Is there any way to force a reload of the page but with the new URL?

Comment: You are going to an anchor of the same page? Then of course it will stay at the same page.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to force a reload (with the new URL)?

Answer (score 4):

in order to force a refresh on the url, you have to mark it as a new url. 
this can be done by adding a unique identifier to the url.
using your example:

```
window.open (url+"?dt="+(new Date()).getTime(),"_self");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a handle on the new window and refresh that.

```
var childWindow = window.open(/* ... */);
childWindow.location.reload();
```

[refresh child window from parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059179/refresh-child-window-from-parent-window)

Comment: But this seems not working if I plan to use the same window. I guess my initial question can't be solved.

Comment: It depends, do you have access to any server side programming?

actually, I think I just found a way - if you append a timestamp to the link. 

something like that
timestamp = Date.now()
window.open("index.html#/TheNewURL?v=" + timestamp,"_self");

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467873/how-to-append-timestamp-to-the-java-script-file-in-script-tag-url-to-avoid-cac